# Application de Stone-Weierstrass

Tags: analysis, approximation

Bonjour,

J'ai rencontré le problème suivant dans le livre "Real and Functional Analysis" de Lang, au chapitre $3$. J'explique d'abord le contexte, puis j'en viendrai à la question précise.

Il faut démontrer que les fonctions de la forme $e^{-x}p(x)$, où $p$ est un polynôme, sont denses dans l'ensemble des fonctions continues sur $[0, +\infty[$ qui tendent vers zéro en $+\infty$, muni de la norme sup.

Pour cela, on applique Stone-Weierstrass au complété $[0,+\infty]$, en considérant l'algèbre des fonctions de la forme $\sum_{n=1}^{N}{e^{-nx}p_n(x)}$ définies sur le complété (auxquelles on doit rajouter aussi des constantes). Ensuite, il faut montrer qu'on peut approcher uniformément les fonctions $e^{-nx}p(x)$ par des fonctions de la forme $e^{-x}q(x)$.

Lang suggère d'approcher d'abord $e^{-2x}$ par des fonctions $e^{-x}q(x)$ à l'aide de la formule de Taylor avec reste, puis $e^{-nx}p(x)$ en général. Je crois avoir réussi la première partie, et la deuxième partie en découle assez facilement pour $n \geq 3$. Par contre, je n'arrive pas à traiter le cas $n = 2$.

Alors ma question est la suivante: **Pour $m \in \mathbf{N}$, peut-on approcher uniformément $x^m e^{-2x}$ sur $[0,+\infty[$ par des fonctions de la forme $e^{-x}q(x)$, où $q$ est un polynôme?**

J'apprécierais beaucoup une référence ou une démonstration (ou les deux). (Vous pouvez répondre dans une autre langue.)

---

[Mod: attempt at translation below]

Hello,

I've encountered the following problem in the book "Real and Functional Analysis" by Lang, in chapter 3. I'll first explain the context, after which I'll pose my precise question.

We want to prove that the functions of the form $e^{-x}p(x)$, where $p$ is a polynomial, are dense in the set of continuous functions defined on $[0,\infty)$ which tends to 0 at $+\infty$, equipped with the sup norm.

For this, we apply Stone-Weierstrass on the completion $[0,+\infty]$, and consider the algebra generated from the functions of the form $\sum_{n=1}^N e^{-nx}p_n(x)$ (to which we add also the constant functions). Next, we need to show that we can uniformly approximate the functions $e^{-nx}p(x)$ by functions of the form $e^{-x}q(x)$.

Lang suggests to first approximate $e^{-2x}$ by functions of the form $e^{-x}q(x)$ using Taylor's theorem with remainders. Then consider $e^{-nx}p(x)$ in general. I think I know how to do the first step. For the second step, the $n\geq 3$ cases are easy. On the other hand, I don't know how to treat the case $n=2$.

So here's my question: **can we approximate a function of the form $x^me^{-2x}$, where $m\in\mathbb{N}$, uniformly over $[0,\infty)$, by functions of the form $e^{-x}q(x)$, where $q$ is a polynomial?**

I would appreciate a reference or a proof (or both). (You can post your answer in another language.)

Comment: Comme certainement tu as remarqué, ici on écrit en anglais! :)

Comment: Perhaps your browser has automatically translated this site into French for you, but this is actually an English-based site, so I think most people here will appreciate if you could translate your question into English.

Comment: @Mariano: Google Chrome is known to automatically translate pages into the user's preferred language, so it's possible that C.R. had not actually noticed that here we write in English! I've seen this issue raised on meta.SO, but I can't find it now.

Comment: A problem from Lang asks to show that the set $S$ of functions of the form $e^{-x} p(x)$, with $p$ a polynomial, is sup-norm-dense in $C_0[0,\infty)$: the set of continuous functions $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.  From an appropriate version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem one knows that the subalgebra of $C_0[0,\infty)$ generated by $S$ is dense, so suffices to show that any function of the form $e^{-kx} p(x)$ is in the uniform closure of $S$, and it suffices to consider only $p$ a power of $x$.  The OP is stuck on this case, with $k=2$.

Comment: J'ai vérifié dans le FAQ, et je n'ai rien vu au sujet de la langue. Je suis désolé si ça vous dérange, mais je ne voyais pas de mal à poser la question en français. Si vous ne comprenez pas la question, n'y répondez pas, et quelqu'un qui la comprend le fera.

Comment: I don't see any problems with users posting in any language they like. Indeed, if the poster's English is weak, questions will often be more comprehensible when written in his native language.

Comment: I apologize if this is the preferred practice in mathematical circles. I found that I was thinking of [the official policy on the StackOverflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/), but I understand if the people here want to follow a different policy.

Comment: (Continuing the translation of details) You can additionally assume known that $e^{-2x}$ is in the sup-norm-closure of $S$ (this follows from an argument involving Taylor's theorem which the OP knows).  Lang's hint is that somehow this fact is of immediate use in showing that any $e^{-kx} q(x)$ is.  The essential difficulty, as the OP states, is with the case $k=2$.

Comment: @C.R.: I edited in a more-or-less line-by-line translation of your original query. Hope you don't mind. @anon: thanks for the translation you gave in the comments. I double checked my translation against yours, so I think I've roughly captured everything the OP wanted to say. Do let me know if I messed up anything.

Comment: @C.R., le FAQ ne dit rien apropos de la langue... mais l'observation suggère sans doute que le français n'est pas fréquent, non?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I only achieved the part that C.R. took for granted in his argument. Since it's already written, I leave it here for the sake of completeness.

---

Let $p_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} x^{k}$ be the $n$th Taylor polynomial of $e^{-x}$. Then by the Lagrange remainder theorem we have $e^{-x} = p_{n}(x) + \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)!} e^{-\xi} x^{n+1}$ for some $\xi \in [0,x]$.

Therefore $|e^{-2x} - e^{-x} p_{n}(x)| \leq \frac{e^{-\xi}}{(n+1)!} e^{-x} x^{n+1}$ and we want to show that the right hand side converges to zero uniformly in $x$. As $e^{-\xi} \leq 1$, it suffices to find the maximum of $e^{-x}x^{n+1}$. Differentiation yields that the maximum is located at $x = n+1$ and its value is $\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{e^{n+1}}$. On the other hand, Stirling's formula tells us that $n! = \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n} e^{r_{n}}$ with $|\frac{1}{12n} - r_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{120n^2}$. Putting these things together we get
\[
|e^{-2x} - e^{-x} p_{n}(x)| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (n+1)}} e^{-r_{n+1}} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0
\]
as we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Je crois avoir trouvé la solution. C'est une petite astuce à laquelle je n'avais pas pensé. J'espère ne pas faire d'erreur, mais dites-le-moi si j'en fais une.

Tenons pour acquis que $e^{-2x}$ est la limite uniforme d'une suite de fonctions $e^{-x}p_n(x)$, ce qui se démontre par un argument avec la formule de Taylor, lequel j'omettrai si personne ne demande à le voir.

Soit $c > 0$. Par un changement de variable, on voit que $e^{-2cx}$ est la limite uniforme de la suite $e^{-cx}p_n(cx)$. Soit maintenant $r$ un polynôme. Puisque la fonction $e^{-x}r(x)$ est bornée, on a que $e^{-cx}p_n(cx)e^{-x}r(x)$ tend uniformément vers $e^{-2cx}e^{-x}r(x)$.

Autrement dit, les fonctions de la forme $e^{-(2c+1)x}p(x)$ sont dans la clôture uniforme de celles de la forme $e^{-(c+1)x}p(x)$. En posant $\alpha = \frac{2c+1}{c+1}$ (qui peut prendre n'importe quelle valeur $1 < \alpha < 2$), on a par un nouveau changement de variable que pour tout $d > 0$, les fonctions $e^{-\alpha dx}p(x)$ sont dans la clôture uniforme des fonctions $e^{-dx}p(x)$.

Il suffit maintenant de choisir $c$ pour que $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$, et d'appliquer deux fois ce qui précède.

Remarques:

1. Souvent quand je rencontre un argument dans un livre de Lang qui semble marcher presque, mais pas tout à fait, je suis tenté de croire que c'est une erreur. Dans ce cas-ci, je suis allé un peu vite en besogne.
2. Merci aux traducteurs. Traduire peut aider plus de gens à comprendre. Par contre, je ne voudrais pas que les gens se sentent *obligés* de traduire s'ils n'y voient pas d'intérêt. J'ai vu sur une autre page quelqu'un parler d'une " 'translate this and do my work for me' mentality." Je n'ai pas posé la question pour obliger quelqu'un d'autre à faire ce travail. Personnellement, j'aurais été parfaitement satisfait que la question soit laissée telle quelle, même si cela voulait dire que certaines personnes ne pourraient pas la comprendre.
3. Je suis passablement choqué d'avoir fait couler autant d' "encre" (si je puis dire). J'aurais préféré n'attirer l'attention que relativement à la question de maths.
4. Un grand merci à ceux qui ont réfléchi au contenu mathématique de la question.

Comment: Il me semble que cet argument est correct. Hier j'ai écrit un argument que $e^{-2x}$ peut être approximé uniformément par des fonctions de la forme $e^{-x}p(x)$, mais ton astuce m'est echappée.

Comment: Merci. Je l'ai aperçu. Même le cas de $e^{-2x}$ n'est pas évident si on ne majore pas correctement le reste de la série. Initialement, j'avais pris une majoration trop grossière du reste intégral. Mais en l'intégrant par parties, on en obtient une convenable, ou bien on peut utiliser la forme de Lagrange, comme vous l'avez fait.

Comment: L'argument de Theo Buehler ci-dessous me semble entièrement correct.